# Can I load RVM as a background process and silence its job control message?

Tags: shell, rvm, zsh

I need to  Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*  , so I execute this script in my zshrc.

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

However, this script will slow me down about 1 seconds whenever I  launch a new terminal. So I figure out a solution which put this script to background job like this:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" &
```

Then I got a quick launch time when I launch a new terminal. But I'll see this message:

```
[1]  + done       source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

1. Is there a better way to make this script don't slow down my terminal launch time?
2. how to suppress this "done" message when this background job done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not work for things like rvm. rvm relies on being able to manipulate your current shell's environment (define its own shell functions etc). When you put a job in a background it is run in a sub-process that has no effect on the current shell. Example:

```
[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~] print $some_var

[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~] cat the-file
some_var=some_value
[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~] source the-file &
[1] 17090
[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~]
[1]  + done       source the-file
[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~] print $some_var

[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~] source the-file
[0 mbunkus@chai-latte ~] print $some_var
some_value
```

If rvm is too slow for you then you could also check out [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) which does something similar to rvm but with much less shell magic.

Answer (score 3):

#### Analysis

You can't do what you're asking, because RVM must be sourced in the current shell. It's also unlikely that your problem is actually RVM; have you actually timed it?

I profiled it repeatedly, and my *slowest* time is under 2/10ths of a second:

```
$ time "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"

real        0m0.165s
user        0m0.068s
sys         0m0.036s
```

It's true that RVM has some processing overhead with the *cd* command (on the close order of ~60ms according to [this blog entry](http://niczsoft.com/2011/11/what-you-should-know-about-rbenv-and-rvm/)), but it's miniscule. Other approaches such as rbenv just move the overhead elsewhere.

#### Solution

Time RVM on your own system. Then time `source ~/.bashrc` or whatever startup files you're invoking. Chances are, it's something else in your shell initialization that's bogging you down.

For example, on my system, an interactive shell takes around 8/10ths of a second to load:

```
$ time bash -ic 'exit' > /dev/null 2>&1

real        0m0.853s
user        0m0.320s
sys         0m0.148s
```

Only 19% of that time is spent loading RVM--and even so, the whole thing loads in well under one second. That seems pretty reasonable to me.